Nuxt: wait for component to be created in SSR
I want to "synchronize" components in Nuxt, on server-side:

component A fetches data and patches a store
a sibling component using the same store should wait until component A is created, to be sure that the data is available

I tried to use Vue components lifecycle hooks @vue:created or events but it did not work. Here is what I tried on a simpler example (without fetch and store):
App.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <ComponentA @vue:created="createdA = true" />
    <p v-if="createdA">Render after Comp A creation</p>

    <ComponentB @compBCreated="createdB = true" />
    <p v-if="createdB">Render after Comp B creation</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>

import { ref } from 'vue';

const createdA = ref(false);
const createdB = ref(false);

</script>

ComponentA.vue (nothing but a template)
<template>
<p>ComponentA</p>
</template>

ComponentB.vue
<template>
<p>ComponentB</p>
</template>

<script setup>

const emit = defineEmits(['compBCreated'])
emit("compBCreated")

</script>

In the end the paragraph "Render after Comp A creation" never renders, with no error/warning, as if the component lifecycle hook did not exist. But indeed it may not exist since the doc says:

Since there are no dynamic updates, lifecycle hooks such as onMounted or onUpdated will NOT be called during SSR and will only be executed on the client.

However the "created" hook does not seem to be executed on the client. Also a previous version of the doc was apparently more explicit (seen here) but it does not fit with the observed behaviour:

Since there are no dynamic updates, of all the lifecycle hooks, only beforeCreate and created will be called during SSR.

Concerning the paragraph "Render after Comp B creation", it does render, but with a warning Hydration node mismatch in the console, which is also not satisfactory!
A StackBlitz test project to reproduce the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-cfq7ar?file=app.vue
In the end I could solve the issue by moving the server-side logic of fetch & store in the parent component (app.vue in the example) since the setup of the parent is executed before the setup of its children, but still I do not understand why I cannot do differently.

"in the end I could solve the issue by moving the server-side logic of fetch & store in the parent component (app.vue in the example) " - it's unnecessary to make a mess of App comp, a proper design is to have WrapperA, etc components just for the sake of hosting the logic that is common between "component A" and "sibling component".

"Since there are no dynamic updates, of all the lifecycle hooks, only beforeCreate and created will be called" - this doesn't mean that @vue:created will work, this is barely documented api, and Nuxt works in its own limited way that may not cover edge cases. What you're trying with @vue:created wouldn't work with your real case any way because "fetches data" presumes it's async op, while lifecycle hooks are sync. This is the case for nuxt apis based on asyncData hook, and this is supposed to happen in a common parent, WrapperA
